# Cannot use ldap_entry in ansible (Missing required 'ldap' module (pip install python-ldap))

Tags: python, ansible

I'm using ansible to update some OpenLdap database but without success. (it complains it does not have python-ldap module installed)

I have the following:

```
- name: Install dependencies
  apt: name="{{ item }}" state=present
  with_items:
    - python-pip
    - libsasl2-dev
    - libldap2-dev
    - libssl-dev

- name: Upgrade pip
  command: pip install --upgrade pip

- name: Install python-ldap
  command: pip install python-ldap

- name: Make sure we have a parent entry for users
  ldap_entry:
    dn: ou=Developers,dc=myCompany,dc=com
    objectClass: organizationalUnit
    server_uri: ldap://someIp/
    bind_dn: cn=admin,dc=myCompany,dc=com
    bind_pw: somePass
```

If I run pip freeze (on ansible defined hosts) it lists python-ldap==2.4.22 among the other modules, so the ldap python library is installed (I also created a sample py script where I imported ldap module and worked). **I have no ideea why when ansible runs ldap_entry it fails to import python-ldap module.**

```
TASK [openldap-add-users : Make sure we have a parent entry for users] *************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [someIp]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Missing required 'ldap' module (pip install python-ldap)."}
```

Comment: Could you check which `python` has the `ldap` module installed ?. Try `python -c 'import ldap'` and see if it raises error. If it raises error, then run `python -m pip install python-ldap`. That should fix it

Comment: @hansolo - 2.7 (I run pip --version and got: pip 19.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)
)

Comment: @hansolo running "python -c "import ldap" in console does not raise any error

Comment: @hansolo - python default version is 2.7.12 (running python --version gives that version)

Comment: we could look in the ansible code and see why it is not loading ? Add a `print(sys.version, sys.path)` before the line in [source](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/net_tools/ldap/ldap_attr.py#L161)

Comment: @hansolo how can I do that? I installed ansible on my mac, but cannot find source file for ldap_entry...

Comment: Have you installed the module on the machine running ansible?

Comment: @AlassaneNdiaye - I installed it on my mac too (except it has version 3.2.0 - python-ldap==3.2.0 while on hosts it has 2.4.22)

Comment: I found the issue...on target machine were 2 python installed (2.7 and 3.5.2) and I wrongly assumed the default one was 2.7 (running python -version gives me 2.7.2). It appears ansible was using python3 which does not have that moduled installed. I run ansible-playbook -e 'ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python2' openldap-add-users.yml and is working

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the ansible documentation for [ldap_entry](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ldap_entry_module.html), it says:

> The below requirements are needed on the host that executes this
> module.
>
> python-ldap

If I am not mistaken, that means the module needs to be installed on the machine executing the playbook, not on the target machine.

Comment: I found the issue...on target machine were 2 python installed (2.7 and 3.5.2) and I wrongly assumed the default one was 2.7 (running python -version gives me 2.7.2). It appears ansible was using python3 which does not have that modulesd installed. I run ansible-playbook -e 'ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python2' openldap-add-users.yml and is working